# Allocating dynamic memory using malloc in C

Tags: c, malloc, allocation

I'm new to C and have been trying to tackle this question. It's a continuation of [the last thread I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128851/allocating-memory-to-2d-array-using-an-array-of-null-c/50136724#50136724). I made some progress but still have so much to learn and fix.

In short:

In this question a "vector" is a one dimensional array of integers. Therefore an array of vectors would be a two dimensional array that holds one dimensional arrays inside him.

I need to use these variables:

- int** vectors- the 2D array
- int size -an integer that represents how many vectors exist inside **vectors
- int* sizes-a 1D array of integers that represents the length of the vectors

I need to write the following functions:

- **int init(int ***vectors, int **sizes, int size)**
  the function allocated memory to **vectors and *sizes with size and initializes vectors to be full of NULLs,and sizes to be full of zeros.
- **int set(int **vectors, int *sizes, int index, int *tmp, int tmp_size)**
  the function receives an array of nulls (**vectors)), frees the vector inside **vectors whose index is index and allocates memory for a new vector, whose length is tmp_size and places inside it *tmp's elements.

This is my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int init(int*** vectors, int** sizes, int size)
{
    int i, k,j;
    *sizes = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if (*sizes == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        (*sizes)[j] = 0;
    }

    *vectors = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
    if (*vectors == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        (vectors)[i] = NULL;
    }
    return 1;
}
int set(int **vectors, int *sizes, int index, int *tmp, int tmp_size)
{
    if ((vectors)[index] != NULL)
    {
        free((vectors)[index]);
    }
    (vectors)[index] = (int*)malloc(tmp_size * sizeof(int));
    if ((vectors)[index] == NULL)
        return 0;
    for (int b = 0; b < tmp_size; b++)
    {
        (vectors)[index][b] = tmp[b];
    }
    sizes[index] = tmp_size;
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    int size, i, length, indexhere;
    int** vectors = NULL;
    int* sizes = NULL;
    int* tmp = NULL;
    int* p = &vectors;
    int tempindex;
    printf("\nPlease enter an amount of vectors:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    init(p, &sizes, size);

        printf("Enter index\n");
        scanf("%d", &indexhere);
        printf("Enter Length\n");
        scanf("%d", &length);
        tmp = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
            printf("Enter elements:\n");
            for (int g = 0; g < length; g++)
                scanf("%d", &tmp[g]);
            set(&vectors, sizes, indexhere, tmp, length);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Could someone explain please why the program always crashes?

Comment: This is the perfect time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). More specifically, if you run your program in a *debugger* it will catch the crash, and allow you to walk up and down the function call stack, so you can locate exactly where it happens in your code. You can also examine variables and their values to make sure they are okay.

Comment: If, after examining in a debugger, you still can't figure it out, then you need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, and tell us where in your code the crash happens.

Comment: I used visual studio's debuger and I think whenever I input index in main(), vectors[3] changes its value from NULL to something else. It's always vectors[3] and always after index...no idea why.Thank you for informative links and for the time taken in writing your replies.

Comment: So you think the problem is in `main()` but do not show the code of that? Please make a [mcve].

Comment: I apologise, I completely agree with you, I thought I added main()

Comment: added the minimal main(), i can replicate the problem only with the code above now

Comment: `size` is potentially uninitialized in `init(p, &sizes, size);`.

Comment: Don't the compiler shout warnings at you? The variable `p` is not of the correct type. *And* you pass the wrong type as first argument to `set` as well (which is the probable cause of your crash). Listen to your compiler.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude visual studio 2017 doesn't show any warnings or errors

Comment: Then you should enable more warnings. The compiler is definitely able to detect such things.

Comment: YOU can find the details about the options to the visual studio compiler at: [options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx).  Use those warnings when compiling, then fix the resulting compiler messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In `init` function `(vectors)[i] = NULL;` should actually be `(*vectors)[i] = NULL;`
2. When calling `set` function from `main` you should pass `vectors` instead of `&vectors`.

There also seems to be several pointer type mismatches in your code, so you should really pay attention to compiler's warnings. This is because C unfortunately allows implicit conversions between incompatible pointers, unlike C++ for example.

Comment: thank you,it solved some of my problems, thank you so much for taking the time in reading my wall text and responding.

Answer (score 1):

You call `set` like this

```
set(&vectors, sizes, indexhere, tmp, length);
```

but the first argument is declared as an `int **`. By passing `&vector` you're passing a pointer to `vector`, i.e. something of type `int ***`. This mismatch will lead to *undefined behavior* and probable crashes.

Comment: thanks for taking the time in explaining what was wrong,it helped me fix some of the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void destroyVectors(int **vectors, int size)
{
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    free(vectors[i]);
}
}

int init(int*** vectors, int** sizes, int size)
{
int i, j;
*sizes = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
if (*sizes == NULL)
    return 0;
for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
{
    (*sizes)[j] = 0;
}

*vectors = (int**)malloc(size * sizeof(int*));
if (*vectors == NULL)
    return 0;
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    (*vectors)[i] = NULL;
}
return 1;
}
int set(int **vectors, int *sizes, int index, int *tmp, int tmp_size)
{
if ((vectors)[index] != NULL)
{
    free((vectors)[index]);
}
(vectors)[index] = (int*)malloc(tmp_size * sizeof(int));
if ((vectors)[index] == NULL)
    return 0;
for (int b = 0; b < tmp_size; b++)
{
    (vectors)[index][b] = tmp[b];
}
sizes[index] = tmp_size;
return 1;
}

int main()
{
int size = 0, length = 0, indexhere = 0;
int** vectors = NULL;
int* sizes = NULL;
int* tmp = NULL;

printf("\nPlease enter an amount of vectors:\n");
scanf("%d", &size);
init(&vectors, &sizes, size);

printf("Enter index\n");
scanf("%d", &indexhere);

printf("Enter Length\n");
scanf("%d", &length);

tmp = (int*)malloc(length * sizeof(int));
printf("Enter elements:\n");
for (int g = 0; g < length; g++)
    scanf("%d", &tmp[g]);

set(vectors, sizes, indexhere, tmp, length);

for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    printf("byte: %d\n", vectors[indexhere][i]);

printf("sizes index: %d\n", sizes[indexhere]);

free(tmp);
free(sizes);
destroyVectors(vectors, size);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the time taken into fixing and replying,much appreciated.i managed to fix my program with everyone's suggestions and even the other functions work,but more ways of writing the same thing are always appreciated and welcomed.